# How to remove some word in a sentences Java?

Tags: java, string

Assume the string is:

`The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl`

How can I remove character after `/` and the out put as below
`The Fulton County Grand`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a simple regex-based replace could work fine here:

```
text = text.replaceAll("/\\S*", "");
```

Here the `\\S*` means "0 or more non-whitespace characters". There are other options you could use too, of course.

Answer (score 5):

```
String input = "The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl";
String clean = input.replaceAll("/.*?(?= |$)", "");
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl";
    String clean = input.replaceAll("/.*?(?= |$)", "");
    System.out.println( clean);
}
```

Output:

```
The Fulton County Grand
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = "The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl";
String newText = text.replaceAll("/.*?\\S*", "");
```

From Java API:

```
String  replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

String  replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

String  replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

String  replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
```

If you need to replace a substring or a character, use 1st 2 methods.
If you need to replace a pattern or a regex, used 2nd 2 methods.

Comment: huh? how does this work? did you test the output? (hint: it doesn't work)

Comment: This will just remove the slashes, the OP wants to remove the characters following the slash as well.

Comment: Oh, sorry, It's still mornign here

Answer (score 1):

do as follow:

**startchar** : is a starting character from which you want to replace.

**endchar**   : is a ending character up to chich character you want to replace.

**" "**        : is because you just want to delete it so replace with white space

```
string.replaceAll(startchar+".*"+endchar, "")
```

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

also see [greedy quantifier examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

see working example

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String startchar ="/";
        String endchar="?(\\s|$)";
    String input = "The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl";
    String clean = input.replaceAll(startchar+".*"+endchar, " ");
    System.out.println( clean);
}
```

output

```
The Fulton County Grand
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
String text = "The/at Fulton/np-tl County/nn-tl Grand/jj-tl";
String newText = text.replaceAll("/.*?(\\s|$)", " ").trim();
```

Yields:

> The Fulton County Grand

This basically replaces any character(s) which are after a `/` and are either followed by a white space or else, by the end of the string. The `trim()` at the end is to cater for the extra white space added by the `replaceAll` method.